# Changing the body of a function in an instance of a class

Tags: java, function, class, parameters

In a class called `Button` I have a function called `onClick()`. I have 2 instances of `Button` class. By default, `onClick()` is empty - (Here's the definition: `public void onClick () {}`). In another class called `MainMenuScreen` I make the 2 instances of `Button` but I need a way to change the body of the `onClick()` button for each of them separately. If that is impossible, I would need a way to take a function as a parameter in another function, like this: `void function (void param) {}` but I'm not sure if that's possible anyway. If you need to see more of my code then just write a comment.

Comment: please share ref code for it. Also are you using any scripting language for it?

Comment: No I'm not using a scripting language, just Java. Also what's ref code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the classes and override the method. The extended classes can be defined inside the MainMenuScreen class:

```
    class OtherButton extends Button {
        @Override
        public void onClick(){
            //new logic
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pedro's example will work perfect for what you are doing. As a freebie here are a few more ways you can accomplish this.

If Button only needs to define what it can do then it should be an interface and have the specific Buttons implement it. This becomes an advantage when dealing with large applications because it allows you to decouple your code by using the [dependency inversion principle](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).

```
public interface Button {
    public void onClick();
}

public class OtherButton implements Button {
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
        //new logic
    }
}
```

For your purpose you should use inheritance like the examples above. However you asked about passing functionality into a method, and yes you can do this. Java 8 makes this fairly easy with [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Use can put the logic directly in the body of the lambda
    onClick((Void v) -> {System.out.println("Button Clicked"); return null;});

    //Or you can use this to pass another method in
    onClick((Void v) -> {customOnClick(); return null;});
}

public static void customOnClick() {
    System.out.println("Button Clicked: customOnClick");
}

public static void onClick(Function<Void, Void> action) {
    action.apply(null);
}
```

In versions below Java 8 you can use an anonymous functions to pass functionality into a method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    onClick(new Action() {
        public void doAction() {
            System.out.println("Button Clicked");
        }
    });
}

public static void onClick(Action action) {
    action.doAction();
}

public interface Action {
    public void doAction();
}
```